# Report parameters come disabled on browser

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

When I am trying to brows my SSRS report on browser , parameters come disabled.
Its happening almost on all browsers.

[image]

I tried :-

1. Clearing browser history
2. Setting script manager mode to :- ScriptMode="Release"

What can be the problem ?

Comment: Is the report a snapshot? If you are using snapshots of the data the parameters will be greyed out.

Comment: How to cehck if report is snaptop ?

Comment: If you are showing a report that was generated before, where the query runs at some interval then its a snapshot. If you are using the parameters in a query directly then it is being generated then and the parameters will be enabled. If you click on the drop down arrow in the report manager and select View Report history, if that shows a history of reports, you probably using snapshots. There are a couple of ways to generate report snapshots, so the real question is how are you generating these reports?

Comment: It is not snapshot report

Comment: Do you have any hidden, or internal parameters in the report that the visible ones depend on their values for?

Comment: Are your parameters' **Available Values** (or Defaults) from a query? You may not be getting any results from the query for the parameter or your 1st parameter may be dependent on another parameter. The parameters must be ordered in the list correctly if they are cascading.